# Reverting commit in git

Tags: git

So that is the question:

how to revert to specific commit in history while saving current work to another branch?

I've tried checking out to another branch and then `git reset --hard commit_hash` but the other branch was reverted too and i don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

If the work is not yet committed you can stash the uncommitted work, revert the commit and then pop the stash.

If the work was already committed you can checkout another branch, revert to the commit previous to the undesired commit and then [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the work that came after.

Answer (score 0):

> how to revert to specific commit in history while saving current work to another branch?

```
// create new branch from the current code    
git branch <full_branch_name>

// reset the current branch to the desired point in time
git reset HEAD --hard <commit_id>
```

Now your current branch is pointing to the desired commit while the  contains all the latest commits made into the original branch.

You can simply checkout the  to view that latest work you have done so far.